# How do I create an Array of Objects in C?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, typedef

I'm new to C, coming from a language like javascript the amount of types, keywords etc. in the language are painfully confusing.

In javascript I can create an array of objects like so.

```
arrayOfObjectsInsideJavascript = [
    { s:"ejf09j290fj390j2f09", f=0 },
    { s:"dj320992209920209dj", f=0 }
]
```

From what I've read it seems that I'll need to be using `typedef`and or`struct`s.

I've tried:

```
typedef struct[] = {
    { s:"ejf09j290fj390j2f09", f=0 },
    { s:"dj320992209920209dj", f=0 }
}

struct[] = {
    { s:"ejf09j290fj390j2f09", f=0 },
    { s:"dj320992209920209dj", f=0 }
}

typedef struct {
    char[] s = "ejf09j290fj390j2f09";
    int f = 0; 
} objectLikeClassThingy;
```

What's the best way to create the object I need?

Comment: well there is no concept of `classes and objects` in C as it's not object oriented so I think question would rather be `How do I create an Array of structures in C?`

Comment: I don't get the point of this comment, if I didn't know how to even create a structure why are you telling me I should've named the question "How do I create an Array of structures in C?"

Comment: well then answer to you question is **You can't** as there is no concept of objects (instances of a class) in C...

Comment: `What's the best way to create the object I need?`

I explicitly ask for the best way to create what I'm going for, not What's the best way to create a javascript array and a javascript object in C.
Saying I can't is being pedantic.

Comment: @CherubimAnand You're confusing Java and JavaScript. JavaScript does not have classes, and objects are essentially hash maps.

Comment: "What's the best way to create the object I need?" - Learn the language and write C code. Without knowledge of C you are doomed to permanent problems in C. This is not a language for trial&error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where JavaScript has dynamic "properties", C has static "tags". A struct type is defined as a sequence of tags, which each have a type.

For the type inside your example array

```
arrayOfObjectsInsideJavascript = [
    { s:"ejf09j290fj390j2f09", f=0 },
    { s:"dj320992209920209dj", f=0 }
]
```

your last solution started off almost correctly:

```
struct element {
    char s[256];
    int f;
};
```

You have two options for the type of `s`:

- If you want to store the string inside the object, you use some array type, such as `char s[256]`. `256` is the length of the array, so when you use zero-terminated strings, the maximum allowed string length is 255 (which is 256, minus one for the `'\0'` character).
- If you want to store the string outside the object, you use some pointer type. Since you want to use string literals, you should declare the tag as `const char *s`. Changing a string literal causes undefined behaviour, so it's best to prevent yourself from doing so.

For this answer, I'll use the first option in the examples.

---

If you want to define *one* struct, you could now write something like

```
struct element {
    char s[256];
    int f;
} one_object = {
    .s = "ejf09j290fj390j2f09",
    .f = 0,
};
```

or

```
struct element {
    char s[256];
    int f;
};

/* ... later, in a scope where `struct element` is visible ... */

struct element one_object = {
    .s = "ejf09j290fj390j2f09",
    .f = 0,
};
```

or, with a `typedef`,

```
typedef struct {
    char s[256];
    int f;
} your_element_type;

/* ... later, in a scope where `your_element_type` is visible ... */

your_element_type one_object = {
    .s = "ejf09j290fj390j2f09",
    .f = 0,
};
```

Note that this doesn't necessarily work with older compilers that don't support the C99 standard. In the older days, you'd have to initialise fields in order:

```
your_element_type one_object = { "ejf09j290fj390j2f09", 0 };
```

Also note that, if you're never going to refer to the type name `struct element` again, you don't *have to* name it:

```
struct {
    char s[256];
    int f;
} one_object = {
    .s = "ejf09j290fj390j2f09",
    .f = 0,
};
```

---

Arrays are initialised similarly (you've actually already initialised an array, namely `s`, with a string):

```
struct element {
    char s[256];
    int f;
} so_many_objects[] = {
    { .s = "ejf09j290fj390j2f09", .f = 0 },
    { .s = "dj320992209920209dj", .f = 0 },
};
```

or

```
struct element {
    char s[256];
    int f;
};

/* ... later, in a scope where `struct element` is visible ... */

struct element so_many_objects[] = {
    { .s = "ejf09j290fj390j2f09", .f = 0 },
    { .s = "dj320992209920209dj", .f = 0 },
};
```

or, with a `typedef` again,

```
typedef struct {
    char s[256];
    int f;
} your_element_type;

/* ... later, in a scope where `your_element_type` is visible ... */

your_element_type so_many_objects[] = {
    { .s = "ejf09j290fj390j2f09", .f = 0 },
    { .s = "dj320992209920209dj", .f = 0 },
};
```

By the way, note that we are using an incomplete type for `so_many_objects`; this is only possible because the compiler can see how big the array should be. In these examples, the compiler would treat your code as if you'd have written `struct element so_many_objects[2]`. If you think you'll have to extend the array with more objects, you'd better specify how many elements the array has (at maximum), or learn about dynamic allocation.

Comment: When you initialise an instance of the struct, why  do you have to put a `.` before the variable name?

Comment: @dev In that syntax, the dot serves to distinguish between a variable names and tag names. Assignments are also expressions. If you would write `struct element aaaa = { bbbb = "foo", cccc = 0 };`,  not only would you declare and initialise the object `aaaa`, but you would also assign values to the variables `bbbb` and `cccc` *outside of `struct element`*.

Comment: @dev Also, the only reason that `struct element aaaa = { bbbb = "foo", cccc = 0 };` would work (if it does) is that the "old style" initialiser syntax applies; it's almost the same as `struct element aaaa = { "foo", 0 };`

Answer (score 4):

like this ?

```
struct  {
    const char *s;
    double f;
} obj[] = {
    { .s = "ejf09j290fj390j2f09", .f = 0 },
    { .s = "dj320992209920209dj", .f = 0 }
};
```